# How to generate k-nearest neighbor matrix for spatial dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, spatial, nearest-neighbor

I have a spatial dataframe with about 3000 points. I want to generate a matrix that provides the k (in this case 30) nearest neighbors for each point.

I can do it using a loop but i feel that there should be an elegant and optimal way for spatial points dataframe class that i do not know of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the fastest is to use `RANN` package - assuming you have `x` and `y`:

```
library(RANN)
m <- as.matrix(nn(data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=rep(0,length(x))), p=30)$nn.idx)
```

gives you a 3000 x 30 matrix of closest neighbors. It is several orders of magnitude faster than a naive quadratic search.

**Edit:** Just for completeness, it doesn't matter which ANN frontend you pick, with `FNN` (suggested by Spacedman) this would be

```
library(FNN)
m <- get.knn(data.frame(x=x, y=y), 30)$nn.index
```

Comment: How does it compare to get.knn from package:FNN?

Comment: Probably the same as they both use the ANN library. For the small sizes here it doesn't matter. The above in FNN would be `get.knn(data.frame(x=x,y=y),30)$nn.index` so pick your favorite :) The results are identical.